# How do I check if my PowerShell is connected on SSH?

Tags: windows, windows-10, openssh

I know how to check but command line cmd or powershell can be altered to make it look clean with disguised hash codes (which they show like they are not tempered but actually commands are altered and edited) or even faked Also I don’t trust the services.msc for same reason.

Is there any trustable 100% method to understand it?

Comment: What are you asking? How to check if sshd is running or not?

Comment: Possibly he wants to know if you are on an encrypted channel.